# uWSGI project not starting -- /tmp/logs/uwsgi.log permission denied [core/logging.c line 28]

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am recovering a nginx/uwsgi/flask server that had been up for about a year. It was originally setup mostly following:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I have it back running such that nginx is serving static files, and I can run the flask app. However, the uwsgi gateway doesn't appear to work right.

When I attempt to start he project: `sudo start myproject` in the digital ocean example, it just says:

> myproject stop/waiting

`/var/log/upstart/myproject.log` says:

> /tmp/logs/uwsgi.log permission denied [core/logging.c line 28]

So, I am wondering what permissions I should have on the log file? I currently have www-data.myuser 764.

Comment: try giving permission 766

Answer (score 2):

The log file must be owned by the user which runs the uwsgi process. In case with Digital Ocean tutorial this is the `user` user.
Please, note that Digital Ocean literally declares the following in the /etc/init/myproject.conf:

```
setuid user
setgid www-data
```

If you copy-pasted the code, try changing `setuid user` to `setuid www-data`. `0644` should be enough with proper user.